# Relative paths not set at debugging, Why?

Tags: c++, xml-parsing, relative-path

I retrieve the values using simple C++ code to check the assigned values of XML Loader and load the XML scenario file by setting relative path like this.

"loader.LoadXMLScenarioFile("relative path");"

But when debugging loader doesn't load the value if we are not setting up the absolute path. 
But its successfully write the values to text file and it's works correctly.
Why it is happen?

Comment: What debugger are you using? On which platform? Maybe your working directory is different when you use the debugger. Are you attaching the debugger to a running process or start your process from the debugger?

Comment: I used Visual Studio 2008 and debug on it to check the values of variable. (I forgot to mention that:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using VS2008 you should double check your debug settings. Especially the path settings for the debugger.
Look at Properties->Configuration Properties->Debugging. Is the working directory really what you expect for your relative path? By default it is set $(ProjectDir) which is not the directory where your executable is.